# Why does $\int(\theta-\hat{\theta})\exp\left\{-\frac{n}{2}(\theta-\hat{\theta})^TJ(\hat{\theta})(\theta-\hat{\theta})\right\}\,d\theta=0$?

Tags: statistics, bayesian, fisher-information

I'm reading about the [derivation of Bayesian information criterion](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387718866) (page 216) and in the proof, it is given as fact that:

> $$\int(\theta-\hat{\theta})\exp\left\{-\frac{n}{2}(\theta-\hat{\theta})^TJ(\hat{\theta})(\theta-\hat{\theta})\right\}\,d\theta=0,$$

where $\hat{\theta}$ is a maximum likelihood estimator for a model, $n$ is the number of data points and:

$$J(\hat{\theta})=\left.-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2\ell(\theta)}{\partial\theta\partial\theta^T}\right\rvert_{\theta=\hat{\theta}}=\left.-\frac{1}{n}\frac{\partial^2\log f(x_n|\theta)}{\partial\theta\partial\theta^T}\right\rvert_{\theta=\hat{\theta}}.$$

**Question: Why is the equality true? Proof or references?**

P.S. if you need more details let me know. The authors use Laplace approximation and Taylor series in this derivation. You can find a picture of the derivation [here](https://ibb.co/d4vtfw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an informal proof (but I bet my statistics lecturer would love it ...):

Since $\hat \theta$ maximizes $\ln f$, it's a critical point of $\ln f$ and Taylor expansion at $\hat \theta$ yields $$\ln f( \theta) = \ln f(\hat \theta)+\frac 12 (\theta - \hat \theta)^TH(\ln f)(\hat\theta)(\theta - \hat \theta)+o((\theta - \hat \theta)^2)$$

where $H(\ln f)(\hat\theta)$ is the Hessian of $\ln f$ at $\hat\theta$.

With your notations,$$
-\frac{n}{2}(\theta-\hat{\theta})^TJ(\hat{\theta})(\theta-\hat{\theta}) = \frac 12 (\theta - \hat \theta)^TH(\ln f)(\hat\theta)(\theta - \hat \theta)
$$hence the """estimate""" (note the quotation marks):

$$\begin{align}\int(\theta-\hat{\theta})\exp\left\{-\frac{n}{2}(\theta-\hat{\theta})^TJ(\hat{\theta})(\theta-\hat{\theta})\right\}\,d\theta &= \int (\theta-\hat{\theta})e^{\ln f(\theta)-\ln f(\hat\theta)}d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{f(\hat\theta)}\int (\theta-\hat{\theta}) f(\theta)d\theta\\
&=\frac{E_{\theta}(\theta-\hat\theta)}{f(\hat\theta)}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

The last equality follows from consistency of the MLE ($n$ large and additional assumptions).